# WCF Singleton throwing Timeout exception

Tags: wcf

My tcp.net Singleton service hosted by IIS (which is set to concurrency=Multiple) is *necessarily* set to Singleton. I don't know if I need Session Required or Reliable Session set on it yet, but currently they're not.

(It’s a video server that takes job requests). After I disconnect from it for a long time from all the proxies that use it, and it sits idle, it eventually throws a timeout exception!! I know I could increase this delay to a very large #, but I want to figure out a couple things foist:

1. Is there a way, from within the singleton, to say, “Hey, I don’t want to run any longer, nobody’s connected to me for a long time?” and do it *cleanly*?
2. Where, in the singleton, do I trap the timeout exception that is getting thrown and possibly catch it and then possibly exit the service or just silently digest it? I don’t think it’s any of my outgoing calls from the service to the callbacks, and I know I’m returning from each of my methods that I get called upon, so where would I trap it?
3. If a singleton is supposed to “live forever” or “until the host shuts down”, what is the POINT of having it throw a timeout error if nobody’s contacted it in a long time?

Or… possibly…I have a bug in my system and the timeout exception isn’t getting thrown because nobody’s called it in a long time, but because of something else? I'm still looking into this.

I ask this question on stackoverflow because I haven't seen it anywhere and useful answers will show up here, hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

(The service will NOT throw a timeout error if there is nobody connected to it.

In my code, I was calling it from various proxies then letting all the proxies sit idle, but not disconnecting them. That was when it would throw the timeout error.

If I disconnect every proxy first, the service doesn't throw the error. But this is only a partial answer. I still want to know where one would trap the error.

Somebody help answer the question part #2?